# Need to load a scala class at runtime from a jar and initialize it

Tags: scala, dynamic, loading

To all -- I'm probably at best a new guy here, trying to wrap my head around scala, and I find I need to do the following:

- Assume I have a scala class on disk somehwere referenced in my classpath.
- I have a scala application that wants to dynamically load this class and call its constructor
- Once I have that class reference, I can use it to set up values in other classes and objects.

In Java, I'd use the Java class loader and create a new instance whereupon I'd call its constructor.  What is the right way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a [blog entry](http://kneissl.eu/Members/martin/blog/reflection-from-scala-heaven-and-hell) quite a long time ago on this. Unfortunately I haven't found the time to update it for Scala 2.8 .

Essentially it boils down to

- do it like you would in Java
- use Scala features to improve the user interface

Answer (score 4):

Scala classes are Java classes, so just do what you'd do in Java. The [Scala Java Interoperability FAQ](http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4) doesn't talk about classloaders specifically, but it might be helpful as you figure things out.