# Scala - Dynamic class loading - class A can not be cast to class A

Tags: class, scala, dynamic, classloader, loading

I have a simple jar file containing class `A`:

```
public class A {}
```

Then I load it in runtime:

```
var classLoader = new URLClassLoader(Array(my_jar_file.toURI.toURL))
var clazz = classLoader.loadClass("A")
```

It is ok, it can load the class `A`. This command is also ok:

```
clazz.newInstance
```

But when I cast it to `A`:

```
clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to A
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with code that uses asInstanceOf[A].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code implies that you have "A" available in one classLoader context where you are calling clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A] which is a separate context from where you are getting the clazz object. **The problem is that you have two different instances of the class "A" in two different classLoader contexts.** An object that is created from one version of class "A" cannot be cast to an instance of the other version in a different classLoader context.

Comment: Thank you. But if I do that in Java, it's fine. Could you please fix my code so I can load a class and use it?

Comment: I'm sorry. Actually in Java I have an interface `I`. `A` is implemented from `I`. When I load `A` from jar, I check if it is instance of `I`, then cast to `I` and use. It is ok.

Comment: @HiBlack - in Scala, trait with no method implementations or vals/vars compiles straight to java interface. Maybe you can make your "A" extend some trait "I", and make your cast then?

Comment: Thanks Neil, I already got problem with `trait` as you said, after that I post this question :-( (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867766/scala-dynamic-object-loading)

Comment: @Rogach: I'm sorry, I meant you, my typo.

Comment: @Neil: You're absolutely right. I need to call as: `var classLoader = new URLClassLoader(Array(my_jar_file.toURI.toURL), this.getClass.getClassLoader)`, then everything is ok. Thank you so much  :-) . (In Java, I don't need to specify parent).

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a very similar problem, in that I observed a `ClassCastException` when casting a dynamically loaded object to an interface implemented by it.
Thanks to Neil's answer, I was able to determine that the `ClassCastException` was caused by having different class loader contexts.

To fix this I used the `URLClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent)`  constructor instead of the `URLClassLoader(URL[] urls)`  constructor.