# ClassNotFoundException when Loading Custom Class

Tags: scala, classloader

So there's a lot of questions and examples around of reading external .class files using a ClassLoader but I'm struggling to see where I'm going wrong.

```
val folderUrl: URL = new File("D:/tmp/").toURI.toURL //file:/D:/tmp/
val cl: URLClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(Array(folderUrl), this.getClass.getClassLoader)
cl.loadClass("my.package.MyClassName")
```

The last line throws a ClassNotFoundException

The folder D:/tmp/ contains a class file "MyClassName.class".
The class has the package "my.package"
The class is called "MyClassName"

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: 
The two closest question which relate are:

- [Scala - Dynamic object/class loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867766/scala-dynamic-object-class-loading)
- [How do I call a Scala Object method using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039822/how-do-i-call-a-scala-object-method-using-reflection)

But these both do not have my problem however, they both get further than I have done where they successfully load the class before running into issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a Scala Object method using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039822/how-do-i-call-a-scala-object-method-using-reflection)

Comment: is this a java or scala class?

Comment: It is a scala class.
The question you linked to doesn't mention any loading from a class file, I don't think it is a duplicate unless I misunderstand?

Comment: Make sure you're using Scala Reflection and not Java Reflection. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

Comment: The docs there only show how to do runtime inspection of the classes, not actually load classes from files themselves which is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific about your particular use case in your question, and how it differs from the posts in your edit

Comment: The first question in my edit successfully calls loadClass in his question. I cannot do that, once I've got that successfully working Ill be able to follow the answers in their questions. I can't really provide a better stack or situation of what's going  since when trying to debug the classLoader code loses me. I'll try again tommorow when I'm back at my desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the fact that the folder structure did not match the package name.

So my folder structure was 
D:/tmp/MyClassName.class
The full class name was
my.package.MyClassName

The class loader requires that the folder structure be
D:/tmp/my/package/MyClassName.class